# Why can't capture the sound speak into my webcamera with parecord?

Tags: bash, pulseaudio

List all input device with commands:

```
pactl list sources | grep -A 5 Source
Source #0
State: RUNNING
Name: alsa_input.usb-SN0002_HIK_1080P_CAMERA_SN0002-02.mono-fallback
Description: HIK 1080P CAMERA Mono
Driver: module-alsa-card.c
Sample Specification: s16le 1ch 16000Hz
--
Source #1
State: RUNNING
Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor
Description: Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
Driver: module-alsa-card.c
Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
```

Capture audio playing on the sound card with same way:

```
parecord -d  alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor  sample.wav
```

It works fine,now to catch the audio speaking into my webcamera with

```
arecord -d  alsa_input.usb-SN0002_HIK_1080P_CAMERA_SN0002-02.analog-mono-fallback sample.wav
Stream error: No such entity
```

Show status of alsa_input:

```
pacmd dump | grep alsa_input
set-source-volume alsa_input.usb-SN0002_HIK_1080P_CAMERA_SN0002-02.mono-fallback 0x13220
set-source-mute alsa_input.usb-SN0002_HIK_1080P_CAMERA_SN0002-02.mono-fallback no
suspend-source alsa_input.usb-SN0002_HIK_1080P_CAMERA_SN0002-02.mono-fallback no
set-default-source alsa_input.usb-SN0002_HIK_1080P_CAMERA_SN0002-02.mono-fallback
```

It is in good status ,why can't capture the sound speak into my webcamera ?
It is strange that the audio speak into the webcamera can be captured with arecord command:

```
#get the hardware info
arecord -L|grep  plughw|grep  CAMERA
plughw:CARD=CAMERA,DEV=0
#write the command  
arecord --device="plughw:CARD=CAMERA,DEV=0"  music.wav
```

Why `arecord` can capture all voice speaking to the webcamera instead of `parecord`?